# How can I run a different py folder that requires arguments using a different py file?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests, arguments

So I found a script from github(Multithreaded Reddit Image Downloader v2.0 (by u/impshum)) that downloads images from subbredits on reddit.com using given input that are arguments -s(subreddit) -i(number of images) -o(order).

```
class redditImageScraper:
def __init__(self, sub, limit, order):
    config = configparser.ConfigParser()
    config.read('conf.ini')
    self.sub = sub
    self.limit = limit
    self.order = order
    self.path = f'images/{self.sub}/'
    self.reddit = praw.Reddit(client_id=config['REDDIT']['client_id'],
                              client_secret=config['REDDIT']['client_secret'],
                              user_agent='Multithreaded Reddit Image Downloader v2.0 (by u/impshum)')

def download(self, image):
    r = requests.get(image['url'])
    with open(image['fname'], 'wb') as f:
        f.write(r.content)

def start(self):
    images = []
    try:
        go = 0
        if self.order == 'hot':
            submissions = self.reddit.subreddit(self.sub).hot(limit=None)
        elif self.order == 'top':
            submissions = self.reddit.subreddit(self.sub).top(limit=None)
        elif self.order == 'new':
            submissions = self.reddit.subreddit(self.sub).new(limit=None)

        for submission in submissions:
            if not submission.stickied and submission.url.endswith(('jpg', 'jpeg', 'png')):
                fname = self.path + re.search('(?s:.*)\w/(.*)', submission.url).group(1)
                if not os.path.isfile(fname):
                    images.append({'url': submission.url, 'fname': fname})
                    go += 1
                    if go >= self.limit:
                        break
        if len(images):
            if not os.path.exists(self.path):
                os.makedirs(self.path)
            with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor() as ptolemy:
                ptolemy.map(self.download, images)
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)

def main():
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Multithreaded Reddit Image Downloader v2.0 (by u/impshum)')
required_args = parser.add_argument_group('required arguments')
required_args.add_argument('-s', type=str, help="subreddit", required=True)
required_args.add_argument('-i', type=int, help="number of images", required=True)
required_args.add_argument('-o', type=str, help="order (new/top/hot)", required=True)
args = parser.parse_args()
scraper = redditImageScraper(args.s, args.i, args.o)
scraper.start()


if __name__ == '__main__':
main()
```

In my second file, get_up.py I imported run.py(the file with the code above) but using run.main() no matter what I try to do here it tells me its missing arguments -s -i -o. Is there a way to input these arguments from get_up.py?

Answer (score 0):

Basically, because `run.py` parser looking for command line arguments, so you can give these arguments to `get_up.py` when you run it, for example:

```sh
$ python3 get_up.py -s (args goes here)
```

instead of:

```sh
$ python3 get_up.py
```

**Please** take a look at https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html